# when click on the sidebar item want to pass some props to to check hide or show some button in the component that the sidebar menu in core ui reactjs

Tags: reactjs, core-ui

I'm using corui admin template,reactjs & redux in my project.I'm trying to make permissions in my project.

at the moment in my DB, I have these permissions defined(check my image)
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Seq2I.jpg)

here is my current view that i want to solve the problem
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIu6G.jpg)

my problem is in this coreui sidebar when i click sidebar element let's say "sub menu1" then in that time i want to pass the permissions i got from DB as props to that component which belongs to the "sub menu1" element im clicking
then after that component in the left side of the image loads, i want to disable or enable register button with that props.

how can i manage this problem with coreui sidebar since i don't know how to manipulate coreui sidebar.

below is my code where it showing sidebar in the main component

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <AppHeader fixed>
          <Suspense fallback={this.loading()}>
            <DefaultHeader onLogout={(e) => this.signOut(e)} />
          </Suspense>
        </AppHeader>
        <div className="app-body">
          <AppSidebar fixed display="lg">
            <AppSidebarHeader />
            <AppSidebarForm />
            <Suspense>
              <AppSidebarNav
                navConfig={_navs}
                {...this.props}
                router={router}
              />
            </Suspense>
            <AppSidebarFooter />
            <AppSidebarMinimizer />
          </AppSidebar>
          <main className="main">
            <AppBreadcrumb appRoutes={routes} router={router} />
            <Container fluid>
              <Suspense fallback={this.loading()}>
                <Switch>
                  {routes.map((route, idx) => {
                    return route.component ? (
                      <Route
                        key={idx}
                        path={route.path}
                        exact={route.exact}
                        name={route.name}
                        render={(props) => <route.component {...props} />}
                      />
                    ) : (
                      <Redirect from="*" to="/dashboard" />
                    );
                  })}

                  <Redirect from="*" to="/dashboard" />
                </Switch>
              </Suspense>
            </Container>
          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

below is the nav.js file that side bar is using to navigate.

```
export default {
  items: [
    {
      name: "Dashboard",
      url: "/dashboard",
      icon: "icon-speedometer"
    },

    // {
    //   title: true,
    //   name: "Theme"
    // },
    // {
    //   name: "Colors",
    //   url: "/theme/colors",
    //   icon: "icon-drop"
    // },
    // {
    //   name: "Typography",
    //   url: "/theme/typography",
    //   icon: "icon-pencil"
    // },
    {
      title: true,
      name: "Administrator"
    },
    {
      name: "Customers",
      url: "/customers",
      icon: "cui-user",
      children: [
        {
          name: "Users Overview",
          url: "/customers/user_overview",
          icon: "cui-people"
          // start

          ///end
        },
        {
          name: "Search user",
          url: "/customers/search",
          icon: "icon-puzzle",
          ///start
          children: [
            {
              name: "sub menu 1",
              url: "/login",
              icon: "cui-people"
            },
            {
              name: "sub menu2",
              url: "/customers/search",
              icon: "icon-puzzle"
            },
            {
              name: "submenu 3",
              url: "/base/carousels",
              icon: "icon-puzzle"
            }
          ]

          ///end
        },
        {
          name: "Carousels",
          url: "/base/carousels",
          icon: "icon-puzzle"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Management",
      url: "/mangement",
      icon: "fa fa-book",
      children: [
        {
          name: "Buttons",
          url: "/buttons/buttons",
          icon: "icon-cursor"
        },
        {
          name: "Button dropdowns",
          url: "/buttons/button-dropdowns",
          icon: "icon-cursor"
        },
        {
          name: "Button groups",
          url: "/buttons/button-groups",
          icon: "icon-cursor"
        },
        {
          name: "Brand Buttons",
          url: "/buttons/brand-buttons",
          icon: "icon-cursor"
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      divider: true
    },
    {
      title: true,
      name: "Extras"
    },
    {
      name: "Disabled",
      url: "/dashboard",
      icon: "icon-ban",
      attributes: { disabled: true }
    }
  ]
};
```

i want to pass props only when a specific sidebar element clicked to the component where sidebar element is requesting.

any help for this, please!

Comment: Just add a prop called disabled with a ternary operator depending on the role submitted from the database to the button, like disabled: dbAnswer == 2 ? true : false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot re-render sidebar of coreui template as the sidebar data is coming from `_nav.js`.

Coreui use import for getting json data so we cannot change it from states or props also you need to understand `React.lazy()` function is used for importing data `DefaultLayout` itself.

The only thing you can do is fetch the permission data at the beginning and import it in `_nav.js` so that you can check in this file weather you have permission to allow user for the specific route.

Make sure you must not provide an empty object or array in else condition you need to remove it from `items` array.

If you are change permission, you need to reload to specify new elements of sidebar.